# TextInputLayout Xamarin(C#)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, android-textinputlayout

I writing app for Xamarin Android.

I try to use `TextInputLayout`

Here is my axml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bck">
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="300dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:hint="Username" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
       android:id="@+id/passwordWrapper"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/usernameWrapper"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="password" />

  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I need to set `Edit Text` on center of screen.

How I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Center horizontally or vertically or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in the TextView

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

or horizontal

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```